Is there a way to link GET Invoices records to GET Journals?
I would like to populate my database with records from both the GET Invoices method and the GET Journals method.  I cant seem to find a common field to join this data?  Thank you
I have reviewed the Xero API Explorer, but have not been able to locate a common field or internal record identifier. GET Journals contains a SourceID, however I do not see a coresponding field for GET Invoices.

You'll need to use both SourceID and SourceType from the GET Journals responses.
Here is a complete list of SourceType - Journal Source Types
Thus if a SourceType was ACCREC, you'll know that the journal was generated from a Sales Invoice with the InvoiceID of SourceID.

Much appreciated Weili.
